# Balancing amount of finger movements when playing through all possible finger combinations on a piano

Tags: combinations, binary

When I was young I used to spend the time of the sermon at the mass, which I considered quite boring, by using my fingers on my legs to represent the digits in base 2 and counting from 0 to 1023. However, not only half of the movements would require more than one finger to move simultaneously but my right hand little finger would do a lot of work, moving 1023 times, while the other fingers would do gradually less work, up to my left hand little finger which would move only once. This was quite a good piano exercise for the 4th and 5th fingers of the right hand (I was studying piano by then), but it wasn't well balanced for all the fingers.

I started thinking at first if it were a possibility to go through all combinations by moving only one finger at a time, without repeating combinations in the process. I recently found out that not only that is possible, but it also is quite a simple thing to do.

However, my main problem still remains up to this day: how can I balance a sequence of all combinations from 0000000000 to 1111111111 so that all the finger work-out is well distributed by all fingers? Since there are 1023 movements in total, I realise it is impossible to have the fingers do exactly the same amount of movements, but can we find a sequence where seven of them move 102 times and the other three move 103 times? If not, how close can we get to these values? How balanced can a sequence be?

Comment: Why not start with something smaller, like three fingers from 000 to 111, then four fingers, maybe even do five fingers, and see whether you find any patterns? Then you could try to prove the patterns you found work for all numbers of fingers.

Comment: By the way, you can't start at all zero and end at all ones. That would require each finger to move an odd number of times, making for an even total number of movements, which $1023$ isn't.

Comment: Do you want your as-balanced-as-possible workout to be one where you only move one finger at a time, or are you thinking of those as two separate problems?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: well pointed, not being able to start at all zeros and end at all ones, but that is not required, only that you go through all the combinations once.

Comment: @Micah: my idea is to have only one finger moving at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a “balanced Gray code.“ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Balanced_Gray_code

Comment: It is exactly that, indeed! Thank you very much. It has some formulas I don’t really understand, but my knowledge of Maths is enough for me to get the gist of it.